# Show or save values in parfor loops in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, parallel-processing, save, parfor

If we use `Parfor` in MATLAB (parallel computing) we can't save values or workspace using `Save('My_workspace')`. Besides that if we simply remove `;` in every line in `For` loops MATLAB show the output in `command window` but in `Parfor` nothing will appear. Everything in `For` loop is normal but when I change `For` to `Parfor` I will get some errors so I need check stream of data and processes in `Parfor`.

I want check steam of processes and data as I can see in `For` loop. How can I do these in `Parfor` structure?

Thanks.

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/135285-how-do-i-use-save-with-a-parfor-loop-using-parallel-computing-toolbox and http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/getting-started-with-parfor.html#bsh16xj-1 see "Displaying Output"

Comment: Thank you for answer Yvon. Using function was true. Please add your answer for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`save` is not allowed in `parfor`. According to [this article](http://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2009/10/02/using-parfor-loops-getting-up-and-running/#11), the transparency is violated. However you can get around this with a function, as a function has its own stack, as shown in [this post](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/135285-how-do-i-use-save-with-a-parfor-loop-using-parallel-computing-toolbox)

```
parfor ii = 1:4
    x = rand(10,10);
    y = ones(1,3);
    parsave(sprintf('output%d.mat', ii), x, y);
end

function parsave(fname, x,y)
save(fname, 'x', 'y')
end
```

The answer to another issue with command window output is "you just can't". See [Mathworks' documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/getting-started-with-parfor.html#bsh16xj-1) (in the last section, *Displaying Output*), and the answer is "no".

Answer (score 0):

Change it to a regular for loop for debugging and then once you have it fixed put it back to parfor.

Comment: Everything in `for` is normal but when I change `for` to `parfor` I will get some errors so I need check stream of data and processes in `parfor`.